# Calabash Tracking Of Closing A Side Menu

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, automated-tests, calabash

Sorry for the confusing title but I can't get my head around to find the right words for this scenario:

We have an iOS app that has a top-left menu button. If you tap it, a side menu opens and most of the screen (incl. the menu button) are slid to the right.

for Calabash I need to track the ID of the view that is slid to the right. Any tap on the whole slid-to-right view area will close the menu. The menu icon itself seems to have no other function than being a visual help and its accessibility ID cannot be found by Calabash while the menu is open.

Does anyone know how iOS handles this kind of navigation? To sum it up:

1. We have an initial view open with a menu button.
2. If button is tapped, menu slides in from left and current view is moved to right (mostly out of the screen).
3. You can now tap any of the remaining visible area of the initial view and the menu will close again (the menu button seems to receive no touch during this).
4. I need to figure out to what assign an accessibility ID to so that Calabash can 'imitate' a tap on the slid-out, initial view to close the menu.

Comment: I think any of the visible UI should be tapable, but I might be wrong. What objects can calabash see in step 4?

Comment: @Lasse actully in the Calabash console it cannot find any of the view elements in the slid view.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the Accessibility Inspector in the Developer Tools of Xcode? This might help you in seeing whether or not you can interact with the slid-out menu.

Also if you haven't tried using the calabash command `tree` - I'd give that a go as well. For that open the menu you're trying to interact with use the command `calabash-ios console` > `console_attach` > `tree`.

You will be able to see the whole view hierarchy here, you can even run tree before and after the menu pops out to see if it makes a difference.